# NoClassDefFoundError for ConstructorAccessorImpl in Java 11

Tags: java, java-8, migration, java-11, noclassdeffounderror

I am migrating from java8 to openjdk11 and I am getting following error in compilation

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/internal/reflect/ConstructorAccessorImpl

Comment: Most of the time you have just to recompile your source. It means during execution a class which you use hasn't been found. By moving from Java8 to Java11 class could also be deprecated and therefore are not useable anymore.

Comment: @Melvin - I am moving from java8 to openjdk11 not  java11. Also I recompiled it but it didn't work.

Comment: OpenJDK11 is Java 11.

Answer (score 2):

The class `ConstructorAccessorImpl` still exists in the Java 11 codebase, but it is now hidden from access by the modules system.

You should look at your codebase to figure out what is using it.  If it is not in your codebase, it might be in a library you are using.  In the latter case, the first thing to check is whether the library version supports Java 9+.

Comment: So if it is using then I have to remove it ?

Comment: That is the best solution.  Application code should not be using private / internal JDK APIs.  But if the usage is coming from a 3rd-party library, they chances are that there is a newer version of the library that fixes the problem.

Comment: It is also possible to "open" the module, but that should be treated as a short term workaround not a long term solution.

Comment: I checked it in the codebase its not coming from there. So it must be coming from 3rd party library is there any way to find out which library is causing it ?

Comment: The stacktrace will probably tell you ... if you read it correctly.

Comment: The strange thing is that the class `jdk.internal.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl` does not exist in JDK 8. In JDK 8, the internally used class has the name `sun.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl`. So this can’t be an issue of the old codebase accessing the former in Java 8.

Comment: Good catch.  The package change appears to have been in Java 9.  So that points the finger at a 3rd party library that took a short-cut in porting to Java 9+.